# No 4inch support from Launch Image when doing Ad Hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using `Xcode 4.6.3` and I'm sending the app to the client via `Ad Hoc` for testing and approval.

However, I've just updated the Launch Images and while it works fine when I run it from `Xcode`, and the 4-inch Launch image shows in the Target Summary, my client has shown me screenshots of the built app running in 3.5inch mode (which is definitely linked to a lack of a 4inch launch image). It's a little bit confusing really as I've named the file correctly (`default-568h@2x.png`) and it works on clean installs on both the Simulator and on my Test device.

I've also cleaned the project and project folder several times to no avail. I've checked the **Copy Bundle Resources** and the original default images aren't there and my new ones are (which is how it should be). I'm completely out of ideas, does anyone know why when it's being archived and distributed (I can't actually get the archived build onto my iPhone as my iTunes is not synced correctly with my phone) the launch image isn't being included thus forcing the app to run in 3.5inch mode?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I've had the same issue loading an image in the application. In my case the problem was that the filename has a capital letter. Double check the name of image and make it lowercase, and then check where in XCode if the name is the same.

Comment: @MarcoPace Thanks for the answer, it's all lowercase though.

Comment: It's Xcode, and Default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Default-568h@2x.png`, just as the other default images are `Default.png` and `Default@2x.png`.

The reason that it works on the simulator and not on the device is the the simulator is not case sensitive, but the device is case sensitive, so you need to use the proper case for file names.